# Complexity class

Tags: algorithm, class, complexity-theory

Assume that methods m1 and m2 are static void and compute the same result by processing an argument of type Object[]. Empirically we find that m1 -> T(N) = 100N and m2 -> T(N) = 10Nlog2N where the times are in microseconds. For what size inputs is it better to use m1 and m2? 
So I would use m1 for big numbers while I would use m2 for small numbers right? just checking the answers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're looking for the value of `N > 0` such that `100N > 10N log2 N`, so that's just an algebra problem. Divide both sides by `10N` and you get `10 > log2 N`, i.e., `N < 2**10`, i.e. `N < 1024`. Not that hard!-)

Answer (score 1):

Well, log<sub>2</sub>N is going to hit 10 when N is 1024, so according to the formulae you've given us, you would use the second one for `N <= 1024` and the first for `N >= 1024`. (What you do "on the boundary" doesn't matter - they'll be equal.)

However, from a practical point of view you should quite possibly pick one and maintain just that one. Do you expect very large inputs, or lots of small inputs? Is this definitely a bottleneck in your code? Which is the simpler algorithm?

There's a lot more to deciding which algorithm is the *best* than just which is the fastest for a given input. I would rather maintain a simple algorithm which runs *slightly* slower than a fast but insanely complicated one.

Comment: No, that's O(n log n) because that's the most significant complexity.

Comment: As I replied to the comment you made in Alex's answer, yes that's right.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+100*n+and+plot+10*n*log2(n)

I haven't figured out yet how to modify the scale though.  In any case, for future reference.

Comment: `plot 100*n and 10*n*log2(n) from 0 to 2048` if you want to set a range. But just using `100*n < 10*n*log2(n)` gives all the results you want.